# Python Seaborn ValueError: These `style` levels are missing dashes

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have data arranged in a clear order. I am getting the error while plotting `seaborn` `relplot`.

My data:

```
plt_table = 

week        01        02        03        50        51        52
year                                                            
2019       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.689206  0.526235  0.679819
2020  0.619076  0.706442  0.693728  0.764938  0.754710  0.755839
2021  0.677132  0.738649  0.683053       NaN       NaN       NaN

#### Seaborn plots
import seaborn as sns
sns.relplot(data=plt_table, kind="line")
```

Present output:

```
    ValueError: These `style` levels are missing dashes: {'26', '36', '47', '48', '49', '13', '20',
 '21', '35', '51', '39', '43', '22', '50', '12', '09', '33', '27', '40', '34', '16', '52', '11', '32',
 '15', '29', '45', '44', '38', '42', '17', '10', '30', '18', '41', '25', '31', '46', '28', '14', '08',
 '19', '23', '24', '07', '37'}
```

Comment: from what I can see, I believe the problem is the data structure of the plt_table, because you have changed the index column to be the year, but then you didn't use df.reset_index()

Comment: @Julia Can you elaborate a bit? I didn't get what you were saying?

Comment: it's really hard to find the error with what you have given, without the full code, but the problem is the empty line after: year                                                            . You should try the fix suggested by Mind Of Aaron and also double check datatypes. The values shown in the error are strings not floats or integers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be trying to pass a multi-index dataframe but it's hard to tell without reproducible code. Did you try running `plt_table.reset_index(inplace=True)` before plugging it into `sns.relplot`?

Comment: I tried your answer. It did not give result. Howerver, after trial and error, I got the plot. I did not create a new dataframe, as I did plt_table above. Instead, I used the dataframe directly. `sns.relplot(data=df,x="week", y="pr",hue='year',style='year',
                       kind="line",palette=hue_colors,ci=None,markers=True,height=4, aspect=1.5)`

Comment: So plt_table and df are two separate objects, correct? Can you post the results of the following: `if isinstance(plt_table.index, pandas.MultiIndex): print('True')` and similarly `if isinstance(df.index, pandas.MultiIndex): print('True')`. This will tell you whether the error was related to plt_table being a multiindex dataframe.